# How to get certain columns of an html table in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to get all elements of a certain column from an html table in python:
for example:

```
a    b    c  
1    2    3
```

I would like to get `a`,1, `c`, 3.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Are you parsing some other HTML code? Or is this all you want to do?

Try looking at [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for HTML scraping.

Include more information on what you've tried doing or more about your project.

Comment: I tried some code from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920623/how-to-parse-a-html-file-with-table-using-python. but I need to get all cells of a certain column (not the whole row)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any spans, it is quite easy to do it. Imagine a table like this:

```
<table>
     <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
     <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

It will render like this:

```
A B C
1 2 3
```

If you take do some string operations on the table code, you can easily populate a two dimensional data structure from which you can extract the columns. The easiest method to do that I can think of is to use regular expressions. Here is a small function that takes the the table code (without the  tags for the sake of simplicity) and returns the list of rows. The rows are returned as lists of cells:

```
import re
    def htmlTableData(tblbody):
    trs=re.findall(r'(?<=<tr>).*?(?=</tr>)', tblbody)
    content=[re.findall(r'(?<=<td>).*?(?=</td>)', tr) for tr in trs]
return content
```

For the above example table it will return this list:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```

Now, just pass it unpacked to the zip function (`els` is the above list):

```
columns=zip(*els)
```

And it will returne a list of columns where columns are tuples. In the above example, it returns `[('A', '1'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '3')]`

Note that you wouldn't really use this in a real scraping program. This is a simple example on how it can be done. In real world, you often have improper code that could never be parsed this way. If you want to do screen scraping, use a parser to get the contents of the table, but zip it this way to get columns.